Accessing DynamoDb from lambda code throws SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings
I'm trying to add a record from lambda into table in dynamodb using enchanced client and java v2 sdk.
DYNAMO_DB = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(REGION)
                .build();
ENHANCED_DYNAMODB_CLIENT = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder().dynamoDbClient(DYNAMO_DB)
                .build();
DYNAMODB_TABLE = ENHANCED_DYNAMODB_CLIENT.table("sometable", TableSchema.fromBean(CompareYourselfModel.class));

 PutItemEnhancedResponse<CompareYourselfModel> response = DYNAMODB_TABLE.putItemWithResponse(PutItemEnhancedRequest.builder(CompareYourselfModel.class)
            .item(new CompareYourselfModel(userRecord.userid(), userRecord.age(), userRecord.height(), userRecord.income()))
            .returnConsumedCapacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL)
            .build());

I have assigned below policies to the Role
AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess,AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole and AWSLambdaInvocation-DynamoDB
I get an exception when below code is executed
DYNAMODB_TABLE.putItemWithResponse(...)

Trace of exception
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build
software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.SystemSettingsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute
software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute
software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DefaultDynamoDbClient.putItem software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.CommonOperation.execute
software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.TableOperation.executeOnPrimaryIndex
software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.client.DefaultDynamoDbTable.putItemWithResponse
Why is access key required for executing code from Lambda? What am I doing wrong?

You are correct - when using Lambda - you do not need creds. You need to setup the IAM role.
This example shows creating a Java based Lambda function that uses the Enhanced Client to interact with a DynamoDB table. It covers the IAM role and the required IAM role permissions.
Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment
UPDATE
I just stepped through this example. I updated to Java 17 runtime as this example is a few years old. Once I did that and redployed - it works great and the DynamoDB Gear table is updated with PPE data, as shown here.


I think the OP is saying that the Lambda function's IAM role does include the necessary DynamoDB permissions yet the code fails, claiming that it can't locate credentials.

I am wondering if the permissions are wrong. In this example, the permissions that are set work

I was hitting the API gateway and checking the cloudwatch logs.Since exception was thrown I made mistake of not actually checking in the dynamo table. The items are getting inserted but the exception is logged.I changed from DYNAMODB_TABLE.putItemWithResponse to DYNAMODB_TABLE.putItem item is getting inserted but that exception is thrown when the lambda app is initialized.Strange issue will accept the answer since its a good example to work with

Glad you made progress
